# Without using L'Hopitals rule, how do you get $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 5x}{\sin 3x}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Without using L'Hopitals rule, how do you get the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 5x}{\sin 3x}$$

Using L'Hopital's, I can just take the derivative of the numerator $5 \sin 5x$ and denominator $3 \cos 3x$ which goes to $0/1$ or zero. But how do you show this without using derivatives?

Is there a trigonometric trick so that the denominator $\sin 3x$ is transformed so the term does not become $0/0$?

Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is one. Does $(1-\cos(t))$ tells something to you ?

Comment: Thanks Claude...took a trip down memory lanes ...thanks for the lead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{1-\cos 5x}{\sin 3x} = \frac{1-\cos 5x}{5x} \cdot \frac{5x}{3x} \cdot \frac{3x}{\sin 3x}
$$
Now appeal to known special limits & limit properties.

Comment: This and @Khosrotash completed my understanding! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

@newbie py: Hi welcome to MSE. there are some methods to find this limit. like below $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(5x)}{\sin(3x)}\\=\\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(5x)}{\sin(3x)}\times\frac{1+\cos(5x)}{1+\cos(5x)}\\=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2(5x)}{\sin(3x)(1+\cos(5x))}\\\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(5x)}{\sin(3x)(1+\cos(5x))}$$ can you take over?

or use $1-\cos(u)=2\sin^2(\frac{u}{2})$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(5x)}{\sin(3x)}\\=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2(\frac {5x}2)}{\sin(3x)}$$

Comment: Thanks for this! The details allowed me to fill the steps of PrincessEev. Appreciate it very much!

Comment: @newbiepy: you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

We have that eventually

$$\cos 5x \ge \cos 6x=\frac{1-\tan^2 3x}{1+\tan^2 3x}$$

then

$$0\le \frac{1-\cos 5x}{|\sin 3x|}\le \frac{1-\cos 6x}{|\sin 3x|}=\frac{2|\sin 3x|}{(\cos ^23x)(1+\tan^2 3x)} \to \frac{0}{1\cdot (1+0)}=0$$

Comment: This was a very cute Idea, But the step $\cos(5x) \ge \cos(6x) , \ x\to 0 $ is working here because the limit tends to zero.

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes of course, but it is true in a pretty wide interval around $x=0$, that is $-\pi \le 6x \le \pi$. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.